# How to create data model as ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I hope to create datamodel objects for database operations in Node.js, much like the style of data models in ASP.NET MVC models, like this:

```
const DataTableSchema1 = {
  employeename: { type: String, required: true },
  designation: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, required: true },
}
```

Is there exist any auto-tools for node.js to create that, or any methodology to make it as simple as ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework did, thanks a lot.